# psfrag or auto-pst-pdf return error: LaTeX Warning: File `filename-pics.pdf' not found on input line

Tags: errors, psfrag, auto-pst-pdf

I am using TeXworks to write my thesis. But I am unable to use psfrag package with auto-pst-pdf because it returns error about a file that I haven't even called in main command line. Instead there is another file called in line 29 which is eps logo of my uni and it is in same directory in which "test" file is. I have tried both name, i.e. "Logo_Uni" and "Logo_Uni.eps" but still same error. And if i comment out Logo from below code the psfrag don't even work and no figure is shown in output pdf.

The Typesetting is pdfLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTeX and test.TeX file is as below

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argminA}{arg\,min}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{epsf}
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage{rotating}
  \usepackage{trfsigns}
    \usepackage{graphicx,psfrag,amssymb}
    \usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

{\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{Logo_Uni}
\end{center}
\end{figure}}


\psfragfig{PL_newTag}{
\psfrag{Sigma}{$\sigma_{SS,k}^2$}
}

\end{document}
```

```
Console Output:

LaTeX Warning: File `test-pics.pdf' not found on input line 29.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `test-pics.pdf' not found: using draft setting
.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.29 \includegraphics{Logo_Uni}

?
```

```
2019-02-02 22:42:38,630+0500 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
2019-02-02 22:42:39,458+0500 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex --synctex=1 --shell-escape C:/Users/mwx416012/Desktop/psfrag_testing\test.tex
2019-02-02 22:42:39,466+0500 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2019-02-02 22:42:39,467+0500 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2019-02-02 22:42:39,467+0500 INFO  pdflatex - allowing all shell commands
2019-02-02 22:42:39,776+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: echo " "
2019-02-02 22:42:39,824+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: echo "-------------------------------------------------"
2019-02-02 22:42:39,853+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: echo "auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation"
2019-02-02 22:42:39,882+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: echo "-------------------------------------------------"
2019-02-02 22:42:40,010+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: latex -disable-write18 -jobname="test-autopp" -interaction=batchmode  "\let \APPmakepictures \empty \input  test.tex"
2019-02-02 22:42:41,363+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: dvips -Ppdf -o "test-autopp.ps" "test-autopp.dvi"
2019-02-02 22:42:41,942+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: ps2pdf  "test-autopp.ps" "test-autopp.pdf"
2019-02-02 22:42:42,985+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: pdfcrop  "test-autopp.pdf" "test-pics.pdf"
2019-02-02 22:42:43,325+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: echo "-------------------------------------------------"
2019-02-02 22:42:43,368+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: echo "auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation"
2019-02-02 22:42:43,395+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: echo "-------------------------------------------------"
```

```
@KJO

2019-02-02 22:56:41,219+0500 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex --synctex=1 --shell-escape C:/Users/mwx416012/Desktop\Hallo.tex
2019-02-02 22:56:41,224+0500 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2019-02-02 22:56:41,224+0500 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2019-02-02 22:56:41,224+0500 INFO  pdflatex - allowing all shell commands
2019-02-02 22:56:41,413+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: echo "hallo"
2019-02-02 22:56:41,604+0500 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 0
2019-02-02 22:56:41,893+0500 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex --synctex=1 --shell-escape C:/Users/mwx416012/Desktop\Hallo.tex
2019-02-02 22:56:41,895+0500 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2019-02-02 22:56:41,895+0500 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2019-02-02 22:56:41,895+0500 INFO  pdflatex - allowing all shell commands
2019-02-02 22:56:41,987+0500 INFO  pdflatex - executing write18 shell command: echo "hallo"
2019-02-02 22:56:42,175+0500 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 0
```

Comment: if you are using pdflatex (which presumably you are if using `auto-pst-pdf` then do not specify `[dvips]` as in `\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}` but in anycase do not use the `epsfig` and `epsf` packages for any documents written this century.

Comment: did you use the  `--shell-escape` commandline option to allow pdflatex to call latex and dvips to use psfrag?

Comment: Yes, I used "--tex-option=--shell-escape" because that enables using auto-pst-pdf

Comment: As per your suggestion i excluded the usage of \usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}, but still get the same error mentioned in subject of this post

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using TeXworks with typesetting as pdfLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTeX

Comment: It would be better if you put the full error from the log in a code block, I tried running your document using `example-image` as the image and got no error (although of course no psfrag replacement)

Comment: @KJO, I think "--tex-option=--shell-escape" is working. Before I tried --shell-escape too but it didn't work. I have added new block of output for test case "hallo"

Comment: @KJO, the logs says 'finishing with exit code 0'. What do you think? shell-escape is working or not? Please check logs in the code block above

Comment: Agreed it seems to be working scratching my head for simple answers, any chance the filename is on a path that includes non latin characters ? is it on the same path as the desktop test ?

Answer (score 3):

> LaTeX Warning: File 'TeXfilename-pics.pdf' not found on input line

Is an indication that either or both `perl` and `ghostscript` were not able to execute the temporary file `TeXfilename-pics`.

We established that in this case shell escape is functioning correctly thus the remaining issue is where on your path are `perl` and `ghostscript`.

To check if they are installed run a windows command console and type

```
perl --version
```

If it responds with the version all is well (otherwise install it)
also check

```
gswin32c --version
```

If it responds with the version all is well (otherwise install it)

Once they are correctly in place on your path any other warnings should not be from these two causes

Comment: I have installed Perl and gswin32c; now its working smoothly. Perfect!