# Problem with subfiles project

Tags: graphics, subfiles

Everyone!

I'm a bit new with latex and I'm trying to create a project with a few subfiles and I found a problem that I just dont understand. I will first put you in context. My directory distribution is as follows:

```
Apuntes/
|Apuntes_radio.tex  (This is the main file)
|paquetes.sty   (This is the preamble file)
|temas/
|->Introduccion/
|->|->Introduccion.tex (This is the subfile)
|->|->img_intro/  (And this is the folder where the images for this subfile will be)
|->|->|->espc_EM.png
```

My main file is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{paquetes}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\title{Apuntes de Radiactividad y Aplicaciones (3º Física)}
\author{Samuel G. Guerrero}
\date{Febrero 2020}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle


\mainmatter
\chapter{Introducción}

\subfile{temas/Introduccion/Introduccion}

\end{document}
```

And the subfile is a bit long, so I'll show you where latex says the problems are:

```
\documentclass[../../Apuntes_radio.tex]{subfiles}

\graphicspath{
  {"temas/Introduccion/img_intro/"} %images path for the main file
  {"img_intro/"}                    %images path for THIS subfile
}

\begin{document}

.....[some junk]....

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{espc_EM}
\caption{Espectro electromagnético.}
\label{fig:espc_EM}
\end{figure}

.....[some junk]....

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.46\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{espc_incandesc}
\label{fig:espc_incandesc}
\caption{Espectro de una lámpara incandescente}
\end{wrapfigure}

.....[some junk]....

\end{document}
```

And the preamble file is:

```
\ProvidesPackage{paquetes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\topmargin=-2cm
\oddsidemargin=-1cm
\evensidemargin=-1cm
\textwidth=17.5cm
\textheight=25cm
\footskip=20pt

\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Tema}} %cambiar "capitulo" por " tema%


\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}{10pt}{}
```

**Now the problem**

As it is, I have no trouble compiling the subfile individualy. It shows me no errors and looks as I want it. The problem comes when I try to compile the main file (Apuntes_radio.tex), it gives me this error:
[image]

the long one saying:

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `\es@period@code espc_EM.pdf' not found: usingdraft setting.See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{espc_EM}

Can anyone tell what it is? I've sorted the 'Missing $ inserted' error before, but this time I'm pretty sure it's not a symbol missing, mainly because the subfile does compile by itself without problems! I've lost a day and a half already to this...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: try to use `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{espc_EM.png}` rather than `espc_EM` without extension.

Comment: Hi Samuel, are you compiling with pdflatex or xelatex?
Did you consult this question? maybe it can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473062/psfrag-or-auto-pst-pdf-return-error-latex-warning-file-filename-pics-pdf-not/473106#473106

Comment: @Annie I've seen that question, but I dont really understand it. I've checked, and i have `perl` but not `gswin32c` installed. And i dont really know what to do. 

About the first question, im compiling with pdflatex.

Comment: i deepen the research: never had this problem .. give me time :)

Comment: Probably appears that the extension is missing in the secondary file: \ includegraphics [scale = 0.5] {espc_EM <file extension>} or it cannot find the directory. Is it possible that the subfiles are in the wrong position in the compilation declaration?

Comment: @Annie I've tried adding the extension (.png) and it has the same error. And I dont understand what you mean by subfiles been in the wrong position in the compilation declaration... Im a bit newbie...

Comment: When you compile the main file, into it indicates all the files (chapters, figures, etc.) that are in a folder, right? if the files are in a different location latex cannot find them and there are often 'file not found' errors.
Since you've been working on it for more than a day and a half to solve this problem let's try to see if the files are exactly in the right folder: you have a folder with 'Introduccion' - inside 'Introduccion' you have a second folder with 'Introduccion.tex 'where are the .png files. that's right?

Comment: @Annie if its worth it, when starting the project I could compile the main file. I should also say that if I comment both figures, the problem disappears and it compiles perfectly. About your question, the files and folders are organized as said at the beginning of the question.

Comment: Let's get the super experts involved! because even for me it is very strange your problem in the final compilation so then we all learn when we are faced with a problem like yours!

Comment: @Annie hahaha yes. Thanks a lot for trying though...

Comment: you are not showing what you have in the "paquetes", but I guess that you are using some spanish settings.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just edited it. You can see what the file has now.

Comment: Try if works if you remove the quotes from the graphicspath declaration.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh my god, that was it lol. Hahaha thanks a lot! wow, such an simple thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes from the graphicspath declaration. Quote are unneeded as there are not spaces (and with a current latex also in the other case) and with spanish they actually harm here as spanish makes the `"` active.

```
\graphicspath{
  {temas/Introduccion/img_intro/} %images path for the main file
  {img_intro/}                    %images path for THIS subfile
}
```